# Jointure with mongoDB and Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, mongodb, uitableview, parse-platform, swift3

I'm trying to create a jointure between "Users" and "Comments" on mongoDB in order to have comments on my app.

This is my code :

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "comments")
     query.whereKey("to", equalTo: commentuuid.last!)
     query.skip = count - self.page
     query.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")
     query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in

        if error == nil {
           // Clean up
           self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
           self.avaArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
           self.commentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
           self.dateArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

           // find related objects
           for object in objects! {

               let infoQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
              infoQuery.getObjectInBackground(withId: object.object(forKey: "id") as! String, block: { (test: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
                 if error == nil {
                    print("YES")
                    self.usernameArray.append(test!.object(forKey: "username") as! String)

                 } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                 }
              })

              self.commentArray.append(object.object(forKey: "comment") as! String)
              self.dateArray.append(object.createdAt)
              self.tableView.reloadData()

              // Scroll to bottom
              self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.commentArray.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
           }

        } else {
           print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }


     })
```

These lines are well executed :

```
self.commentArray.append(object.object(forKey: "comment") as! String)
              self.dateArray.append(object.createdAt)
```

But the one are not :

```
let infoQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
              infoQuery.getObjectInBackground(withId: object.object(forKey: "id") as! String, block: { (test: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
                 if error == nil {
                    print("YES")
                    self.usernameArray.append(test!.object(forKey: "username") as! String)

                 } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                 }
              })
```

I tried to print the usernameArray and dateArray (just to see the difference) in the cellForRowAt function.

When I launch the view, usernameArray is empty and dateArray is Not. If I scroll a little bit, the usernameArray is filled (but I need to scroll to fill the array, which is not acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you are calling to UI related methods before the data has been retrieved:

```
          self.commentArray.append(object.object(forKey: "comment") as! String)
          self.dateArray.append(object.createdAt)

          let infoQuery = PFUser.query()!
          infoQuery.getObjectInBackground(withId: object.object(forKey: "id") as! String, block: { (test: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
             if error == nil {
                print("YES")
                self.usernameArray.append(test!.object(forKey: "username") as! String)

             } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
             }

              // These two methods were the issue.
              self.tableView.reloadData()
              // Scroll to bottom
              self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.commentArray.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)

          })
```

You should consider:

- Using sub-classing `PFObject` to avoid accessing the raw dictionary which could lead to errors due to typos.
- Replacing the keyword `object` with a better one (according to your context, `comment`)